# Chromium Kiosk options

Tags: chromium, kiosk

I'm using a Raspberry PI 3 with chromium and kiosk. If I start chromium as normal, I can enable kiosk and set specific options, namely hide cursor, disable context menu, disable image drag, disable text selection and prevent sleeping.

If I start from terminal using `chromium-browser --kiosk http://www.website.com` the browser starts up in kiosk mode, but with none of these options set.

What I want is to be able to start chromium when the PI boots with all these options configured. How do I do this?

Comment: Good example from start to finish at: https://blog.gordonturner.com/2017/07/22/raspberry-pi-full-screen-browser-raspbian-july-2017/

Answer (score 1):

Add it in autostart script

From /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LDXE-pi/autostart

Where /home/pi is the home directory